# Using `and` with an assignment

Tags: ruby, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I expect the following to evaluate `(a < b)` as well as `(b < c)` and return `no`.

```
a = 1
b = 4
c = 3
@test = (a < b) and (b < c)
if @test
  puts "yes"
else
  puts "no"
end
```

I am not getting the behavior I expect. It returns `yes` and seems to evaluate only `(a < b)` and not `(b < c)`. I think the issue is with `and`.

Comment: Check the operator precedence in Ruby to get the answer.

Comment: This is one of Ruby's few violations of the principle of least surprise, IMO.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `and` instead of `&&`, so actually, you are setting `@test` to the result of `(a<b)`, not `(a<b) and (b<c)` (`=` has a higher precedence than `and`, while `&&` has a higher precedence than `=`).

Comment: I just switched it to && and I added enclosing parenthesis still get "yes". I thought there was no difference between "and" and "&&"

Comment: @Tennesseej: Then you did it wrong. What you need is `@test = (a<b) && (b<c)` or `@test = ((a<b) and (b<c))` or `@test = ((a<b) && (b<c))`. Your original code is equivalent to `(@test = (a<b)) and (b<c)`.

Comment: Yeah I just found a typo in my code, works as intended now. Thank you so  much for your help!

Comment: @undur's last sentence is a wrap.